# IBM IIB/ACE (Soap Request) how to build a ESQL SOAP message with namespaces?

Tags: soap, websphere

I'm tryng to build the bellow XML message in ESQL and send it in a Soap Request Node, but the webservice is not receiving all the fields. One of them is the DocumentList structure, whose Code and Value are being sent empty. Can you help me?

```
<tns0:Envelope xmlns:tns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s00="http://www.outsystems.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns0:Header/>
  <tns0:Body>
    <s00:SentEntity>
      <s00:EntityRequest>
        <s00:Number>2274076</s00:Number>
        <s00:EntityName>JOHN SNOW</s00:EntityName>
        <s00:EntityCategory>NORMAL</s00:EntityCategory>
        <s00:EntityType>PRIVATE</s00:EntityType>
        <s00:ActionToDO>Verify</s00:ActionToDO>
        <s00:DocumentList>
            <s00:DocumentListStructure>
                  <s00:Code>BI</s00:Code>
                  <s00:Value>AOLA005510203040</s00:Value>
            </s00:DocumentListStructure>
            <s00:DocumentListStructure>
                  <s00:Code>HB</s00:Code>
                  <s00:Value>AOHB005510203040</s00:Value>
            </s00:DocumentListStructure>
        </s00:DocumentList>
        <s00:DocumentList/>
      </s00:EntityRequest>
    </s00:SentEntity>
  </tns0:Body>
</tns0:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please post your code and your current output. We cannot propose a solution until we understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please also add the 'ibm-integration-bus' tag to this question. 'Websphere' is not very useful, as it often refers to the app server.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
DECLARE ns NAMESPACE 'http://www.outsystems.com';
DECLARE soapenv NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soapenv = soapenv;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:ns = ns;

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.ns:SentEntity.EntityRequest.Number = '2274076';
-- continue...
```